# how to allocate memory int pointer array inside a function and delete the allocated memory in main.cpp

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to allocate memory to a pointer to an array using a non-template type argument. But, I am getting a run time error at delete ptr in the `main` function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, int SIZE>
void createArray(T** arrPtr) {
    *arrPtr = new T[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        (*arrPtr[i]) = i + 1;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int size = 3;
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    createArray<int, size>(&ptr);
    if (ptr == nullptr)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << *(ptr++) << " ";
    delete ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (*arrPtr[i]) is an uninitialized pointer.  Hard to see the intent, maybe arrPtr[i] = new T;

Comment: Also, when you use `new` with `[SIZE]` you also need the `[]` in `delete[] ptr`. With a plain `int` array it might seem to work anyway, but if `T` has a destructor it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the function instead of this statement

```
(*arrPtr[i]) = i + 1;
```

you need to write

```
(*arrPtr )[i] = i + 1;
```

And in this for loop the original pointer `ptr` is being changed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    std::cout << *(ptr++) << " ";
```

As a result in this statement

```
delete ptr;
```

there is used an invalid address of the allocated dynamically memory.

Change the loop for example like

```
for ( const int *p = ptr; p != ptr + size; )
    std::cout << *p++ << " ";
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `new[]` requires `delete[]`.